# Showing that the Mobius strip is non-orientable using obstruction theory

Tags: algebraic-topology, obstruction-theory

In the notes available [here](http://math.wvu.edu/~fletcher/Applications.pdf), the first example (p. 2) says that the Mobius band is non-orientable because there is an obstruction to a map sending a disk to the band. I don't really understand what's going on here; I've never heard orientablility characterized in terms of attaching disks and I'm pretty sure you *can* attach a disk to the Mobius strip. I really need to understand this example and any help would be appreciated.